# How can I check if SQL Server 2019 Standard is activated on Server Core?

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-server-2019, windows-server-core

I installed SQL Server 2019 Standard on Windows Server 2019 Core from an ISO that I downloaded from our [MSDN](https://my.visualstudio.com). It specifically stated that there is "No product key required" when I downloaded it.

Since I installed it on Server Core, I followed [these instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver15).

If you look at the instructions, there is an `/PID` argument that is needed to tell the setup, what Version of SQL Server to install (e.g Express, Developer, Standard etc.)

However, I did not find a Product ID for the Standard Version of SQL Server 2019. Not in MSDN, not in VLSC and nowhere else on the internet.

The instructions state that:

> SQL Server Setup Control  /PID
>
> Specifies the product key for the edition of SQL Server. If this
> parameter is not specified, Evaluation is used.

Which makes me believe that my SQL Server is now in Evaluation mode. I would like to check now, If my SQL Server is licensed, and also how it is licensed (I should have a license for 4 Cores).

The thing is a bit complicated, since another VM that has an SQL Server with 4 Cores, licensed in another license agreement, is running on the same physical machine, I read that physical cores must be licensed, not Virtual Machine Cores. is my new SQL Server on my new VM now also using the same License as the other VM?

However, my thing is I don't know if my SQL Server is now licensed. I ran the following queries:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> Invoke-SqlCmd -Query "SELECT @@Version" | fl *


Column1   : Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)
                Sep 24 2019 13:48:23
                Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
                Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

RowError  :
RowState  : Detached
Table     : {}
ItemArray : {Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)
                Sep 24 2019 13:48:23
                Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
                Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
            }
HasErrors : False
```

and also this:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> Invoke-SqlCmd -Query "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')" | fl *


Column1   : 15.0.2000.5
Column2   : RTM
Column3   : Standard Edition (64-bit)
RowError  :
RowState  : Detached
Table     : {}
ItemArray : {15.0.2000.5, RTM, Standard Edition (64-bit)}
HasErrors : False
```

However, I am very confused now. It says it's the Standard Edition of SQL Server which seems to be correct, but where did it get the license for it? Is it even licensed? It doesn't say it specifically. How does it know, how many cores it can use?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, the product key is embedded in the MSI (Microsoft Installer) setup program and you don't need to specify PID. Based on the query above you successfully installed SQL Server Standard Edition.

SQL Server uses an honor system for licensing and you do not need to activate it as you do with Windows Server core.

SQL Server Standard Edition is limited to lesser of 4 sockets or 24 cores as per [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/compute-capacity-limits-by-edition-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).